# Laravel parameters without explicitly specifying

Tags: laravel-5

I want to generate the page url without $name, something like this

> mysite.app/statestring

BUT with the route `get('/action/{name}', ...)` i can get only this

> mysite.app/statestring/*somename*

If i changing route to `Route::get('/action', ...)` it doesnt work, the error is "Missing argument 1"

My web.php

```
Route::get('/action/{name}', [
   'uses' => 'DoActionController@getAction',
   'as' => 'returnAction',
]);
```

My Controller action

```
public function ($name)
{
    return view('returnaction', ['name'=>$name]);
}
```

My home page

```
<body>
@foreach ($yourActions as $yourAction)
    <li> 
        <a href="{{ route('returnAction', ['name'=>$yourAction->name]) }}"> {{ $yourAction->name }} </a> 
    </li>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make the **$name** argument optional.

First, declare it as optional in the controller:

```
public function ($name = null)
```

That will get rid of the error your getting about missing argument. Next, make the **name** parameter optional in your route with:

```
Route::get('/action/{name?}', ...);
```

Comment: I need to pass the variable $name to the view and same time don`t show the $name in the link.

Your way is not working because a always pass the parameter